# Is there a right way to interpret a phrase that involves time ex: 'in the last 1 week' or is it always subjective?

Tags: time

If today is 8th April 2022, what is the right interpretation of the term 'in the last 1 week'?

Is it ?

1. 28th March to 3rd April
2. 1st April to 7th April
3. 27th March to 2nd April

Is there a framework of rules that helps interpret phrases that involve time references, like above, in an exact/unambiguous manner?

Comment: When you say "last 1 week" do you mean "last week" or "last 7 days"? The starting day of a week can very by location so where are you considering?

Comment: Please assume that I am a listener and somebody said the above to me

Comment: "last 1 week" isn't a common thing to say - a native English speaker would say "last week".

Comment: How is the term being used? "Over the last week"; "in the last week"; "last week"; "by last week"? All are subtly different.

Comment: I have updated the question. It now says 'in the last 1 week'.

Comment: @StuartF let's say that it was "last week", what would your first interpretation be ?

Comment: "in the last week", in the last year", "in the last two weeks" and similar are common usage but I have never heard the construction "in the last *one* week".  To native ears it sounds strange and confusing as to its meaning.

Comment: I won't 'answer', as I'm sure this is a duplicate, but a hard-to-find one. The longer the time unit, and the more 'round' the measure (5, 10 ...) the more open to approximation this becomes in typical conversation. 'In the last two minutes' means just that. 'In the last 30 minutes' could perhaps allow the last 0 - 35 minutes. 'In the last week' probably means roughly just that (from the start of a week ago yesterday) in loose conversational usage. 'In the last year' perhaps covers 380 days. But one needs to cite actual times of day to make these statements rigorous.

Comment: I would understand _in the last week_ to mean 'in the seven days leading up to today' unless further information was given - the last week of term, the last working week  (usually Monday-Friday) etc.

Comment: *I saw it in the last week" normally means in the seven days before today. "I saw it last week" normally means in the preceding Sunday-to-Saturday or Monday-to-Sunday period. There is a standard (ISO8601) starting day of the week (Monday), but not everybody knows or cares about this.

Comment: Exactly one week ago, for seven days. Otherwise, it can fall on any days of the preceding week.

Comment: Like all attempts at exactness in language, the temporal phrases anchored in the present (_next week, last month, next quarter, last semester,_ etc.) are prone to various usages that contradict one another in different dialects and expressions. None of them **have to** mean any particular thing, since their usages are fixed and social. See [Fillmore's _Deixis Lectures_](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html) to see what it's all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, *in the last 1 week* sounds unidiomatic (although it is not ungrammatical). So let's first consider the less problematic phrase *in the last week*.

There are two distinct possible ambiguities in interpreting that phrase. The choice between **1** and **3** depends on whether Sunday or Monday is regarded as the first day of a week. This is usually a well settled matter within a particular country, but differs among countries. Knowing the country in which the communication takes place will thus make it possible to rule out one of these two interpretations.

The choice between **2** on one side, and **1** or **3** on the other, depends on the context. There is no general rule of English language that would determine which way of interpreting the phrase is **the** correct one, with the exactness and definiteness that the OP seems to seek, and the same is true of analogous phrases, such as *in the last month* and *in the last year*.

The context will, however, often resolve the ambiguity. For example, in:

> If you are considering buying this stock today, you should take into account the fluctuations of its value in the last week.

it is obvious that the hearer is urged to consider the seven days immediately preceding this one, rather than some earlier seven-day period. On the other hand, in

> We may not be able to fulfill our quota for this week, even though we did very well in the last week.

*the last week* will be understood to be the week preceding this one, i.e. the seven-day period that ended on the most recent weekend.

In the first example, *in the last week* could have been replaced with *in the last seven days*, which would have removed the ambiguity completely, while in the second it couldn't have been. I suspect that the OP's formulation *in the last 1 week* was an awkward attempt to create something similar to *in the last seven days* and so force that interpretation. If that is what one wishes to accomplish, one can, however, do so less awkwardly by simply saying *in the last seven days*.

Comment: 'sounds unidiomatic' vs 'not ungrammatical'. According to Orwell, this is probably still 'unacceptable'.

Comment: In the last one week is unidiomatic.

Comment: @Lambie, indeed, as the answer itself says. What exactly is your comment trying to add to the answer?

Comment: I agree with you and disagree, as usual, with Edwin. I should have written: **is** unidiomatic.

Comment: You might also want to mention "in the past week". This is more likely to be equivalent to "in the last seven days", while "last week" usually refers to a calendar week.